# How to join 5 tables (4 subtable + 1 primary) with sql or codeigniter 3 querybuilder?

Tags: php, sql, database, join, null

I have been building a hobby project where I want to write summaries about films, series, animes, tales etc. I want to join 4 tables to 1 main table, but I got a problem. I'm getting null values. At my database the data are exist. But I can not figure out what's the problem with my query.

The concept is as follows. There is an interface where I can record the data. After submitting the form, the controller decides what has been recorded. It saves in the main table what has been saved (anime, movie, etc.) and increases the autoincrement value. It then stores the identifier of the main table and other data (description, title, image, etc.) in one of the subtables. This works nicely. Then I wanted to list the contents of these 4 sub-tables, and here I ran into a problem.

Here is my query:
function getContents()
{

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('contents'); 

    $this->db->join('films',  'films.content_id = contents.global_content_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('series', 'series.content_id = contents.global_content_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('tales',  'tales.content_id = contents.global_content_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('animes', 'animes.content_id = contents.global_content_id', 'left');

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows()>0) return $query->result_array();
}
```

That's what I got back:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [global_content_id] => 2
            [content_main_category] => film
            [id] => 
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [short_description] => 
            [category_id] => 
            [picture_path] => 
            [running_time] => 
            [director] => 
            [release_date] => 
            [language] => 
            [actors] => 
            [main_category_id] => 
            [uploader_id] => 
            [upload_time] => 
            [link] => 
            [status] => 
            [content_id] => 
            [subtitle_status] => 
            [subtitle_language] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [global_content_id] => 3
            [content_main_category] => film
            [id] => 
            [title] => 
            [description] => 
            [short_description] => 
            [category_id] => 
            [picture_path] => 
            [running_time] => 
            [director] => 
            [release_date] => 
            [language] => 
            [actors] => 
            [main_category_id] => 
            [uploader_id] => 
            [upload_time] => 
            [link] => 
            [status] => 
            [content_id] => 
            [subtitle_status] => 
            [subtitle_language] => 
        )
```

Comment: if you join 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 doesn't matter they follow the same principle over and over again, so start with the main and one sub and see if you manage(for that are countless example to find and the take the next

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I modified the question. I have attached the code and the final result. I tried for 3-4 hours but it didn't work. :/

Comment: You should start with inner join and like i said start only with one see if you get your result and then take it slowly also take a look at https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join so that you can understand how joins actually work.

Comment: that all is empty, means only the the joining on for example `films.content_id = contents.global_content_id` has not found any matches. bur as we don't know nothing about your design, we there also can't help you

Comment: Blanks should be expected. If Content has 1-to-many relationship with each of the other tables, a query including all will likely not be what you want. If Content has 1-to-1 relationship with each of the other tables then those 4 tables should be one with another field for category. Otherwise, UNION query the 4 tables and join that query to Content.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help!

That's the solution what I wanted:

```
function getContents()
{
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('films');
  $query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('animes');
  $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();

  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('series');
  $query3 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('tales');
  $query4 = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ('.$query1 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query2 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query3 . ' UNION ALL ' . $query4.') AS bigtable LEFT JOIN ohf_contents ON ohf_contents.global_content_id = bigtable.content_id');

  if ($query->num_rows()>0) return $query->result_array();  


  /*       
    Pure SQL
        
    SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT * FROM ohf_films f UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ohf_animes a UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ohf_series s UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM ohf_tales t) AS bigtable LEFT JOIN ohf_contents ON ohf_contents.global_content_id = bigtable.content_id;
  */
}
```